# Replace element on hover in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css

In this code

```
 <div class='wrapper'>
     <div class='icon'>
        <i className="fa fa-fw fa-globe" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
      </div>
 </div>
```

whenever the user hovers over the 'icon' div, this code

```
<i className="fa fa-fw fa-globe" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
```

should be replaced with this one

```
<p> Lorem ipsum </p>
```

I able to achieve changing styles but don't know how to replace elements. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As with most things in React, you need a state. Something like:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {isHovered: false};
}
```

This state needs to change anytime the user hovers in or out of the icon:

```
toggleHover() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({isHovered: !prevState.isHovered}));
}
```

```
<div className='icon' onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}>
```

Then the logic for deciding *what* should be displayed, depending on that state:

```
{this.state.isHovered ?
  <p> Lorem ipsum </p> :
  <i className="fa fa-fw fa-globe" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
}
```

You may want to have two separate methods, one for `onMouseEnter` and one for `onMouseLeave`, rather than just a shared method for both, like I did.

Oh, and you had a typo: You wrote `class` rather than `className` in a few places.

---

#### Demo

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {isHovered: false};
    this.toggleHover = this.toggleHover.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleHover() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({isHovered: !prevState.isHovered}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className='icon' onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}>
          {this.state.isHovered ?
            <p> Lorem ipsum </p> :
            <i className="fa fa-fw fa-globe" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.icon i {
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/32x32');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition of @Chris's answer, If you would not like to create an event handler then you can create an inline arrow function that does the job.

```
onMouseEnter={()=> this.setState({isHovered: true})}

onMouseLeave={()=> this.setState({isHovered: false})}
```

This is just a shorthand you can go with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use state with onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isHover: false
        };

        this.onMouseEnterHandler = this.onMouseEnterHandler.bind(this);
        this.onMouseLeaveHandler = this.onMouseLeaveHandler.bind(this);
    }

    onMouseEnterHandler() {
        this.setState({
            isHover: true
        });
    }

    onMouseLeaveHandler() {
        this.setState({
            isHover: false
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <div className="icon" onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnterHandler} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeaveHandler}>
                    {
                        this.state.isHover
                            ? <div>hovered</div>
                            : <div>some text</div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```js
function MyComponent() {
   const [myText, setMyText] = useState("Initial Text");
       
   return (
       <div
           onMouseEnter={() => setMyText('New Text')}
           onMouseLeave={() => setMyText('Whatever')}
        >
            {myText}
       </div>
   )
}
```