# To convert IconButton from "Like" to "LikeSolid" on Hover on the button in Fluent-UI

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui

I am new to react. I need to build a "Like" IconButton , when hovered on , it should appear as "LikeSolid" i.e should be filled with color. Can anyone guide on how it can be done.

Comment: Have a look at this. I do believe this question has been answered before. Please do better research before asking questions that already have answers. Here are similar questions;

There are many answers with context attached to them, yours does not. Supply code and context in your questions.


[Replace element on hover in ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671241/replace-element-on-hover-in-reactjs)

[React changing react-icon color on mouse hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214305/react-changing-react-icon-color-on-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 0):

So, pulling from the Fluent UI docs one way we can accomplish this is using the IconButton component and looking at the OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave props that we can provide to IconButton. OnMouseEnter the icon should be solid and OnMouseLeave it should be outlined, so we need to manage that state that keeps those values.

```
import { IconButton } from '@fluentui/react';
import { useState } from 'react';
function LikeBtn() {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const iconProps = hovered ? { iconName: 'LikeSolid' } : { iconName: 'Like' };
  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setHovered(false);
  };
  return (
      <IconButton
        iconProps={iconProps}
        onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      />
  );
}
export default LikeBtn;
```

This is one approach, there are others